# Induction machine: Question regarding field weakening region limited by breakdown torque

Tags: motor, induction-motor, torque

I have a question regarding the entry point to the field weakening region limited by the breakdown torque of an induction machine marked red in the following picture:

[image]

Under nominal conditions, this point may be located at (ws1_N, T1_N) where T1_N is the torque at ws1_N. Let's assume instead of P_N one demands only 0.8 * P_N from the motor. What is the formula to calculate the new entry point to this region ws1_new and T1_new based on the nominal values of ws1_N and T1_N?

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework. Wouldn't we be giving you the answer and depriving you of valuable learning?

Comment: Try to make your own calculations and come back when you are stuck. We can help but do not make your homework

Comment: Well, after some calculations based on the hints of @Charles I got the following: Let´s say we scale P_new = k*P_N then we get ws1_new = 1/k * ws1_N assuming that the stator angular frequency is close to rotor mechanical speed. Is it really that simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty obvious that the range that is being described is the range at which the transmitted torque is limited to the breakdown torque. The entry point for that operation is the point at which the torque for the constant power operation is equal to the breakdown torque. The torque for constant power operation is given by T = P/w where the power is the power developed at maximum torque and w for the point at which the torque begins to decline. You need the formula for breakdown torque. I believe that it is proportional to the square of w at the point at which it begins to decline divided by w. T is torque in Nm. P is power in watts. w is speed in radians per second.

Comment: It seems to me that speed range labeled "constant slip frequency" should not have that label. I would call it the declining power range. I would say that the constant torque range could also be called the constant slip frequency range. Where are you getting your information?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Charles. I have found the formula for the breakdown torque online as `Tb = m*p*((1-sigma)*Us^2)/(2*sigma*Ls*ws^2))`. Did you mean this one? How is the relationship between `w` in your formula `T = P/w` to `ws` as used in the calculation of the breakdown torque? If I understood you correct you suggest setting `m*p*((1-sigma)*Us^2)/(2*sigma*Ls*ws^2)) = P/w` and solve after `ws`, right?

Comment: Please excuse those basic question but I am not really experienced in that field. The term "constant slip frequency" I found today on some web page. From what I have learned today one could possibly also call this region the field weakening range with limitation caused by the break-down torque?

Comment: I think that your first comment is right, assuming that the equation that you have for breakdown torque is correct. Yes also to second comment.

Comment: Could you please help me with the relationship between the `w` in your formula `T = P/w` to `ws` as used in the calculation of the breakdown torque? `ws` in the the calculation of the break down torque means the stator angular frequency (`ws = 2*pi*fs`) . I a quite confused with the relationships of all those `w`, `W`, `Wr`, `Ws`, `ws`, `wr`, `fr`, `fs`, etc.

Comment: I am using w as lower case omega, the mechanical speed of the rotor in radians per second. That is what I believe is represented on the X axis. I would call the speed where flux and torque begin to decrease the base speed. I do not have a designation for the speed at which power begins to decline. Stator angular frequency is close to rotor mechanical speed. That is more appropriate to use for the breakdown torque calculation, but mechanical power can only be calculated accurately using mechanical speed.

Comment: BTW: "Stator angular frequency is close to rotor mechanical speed." Here you mean "Stator angular frequency is close to rotor mechanical speed divided by the number of pole pairs", or?